# pumping lemma for very simple regular expression

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

Pumping lemma definition (from wiki)

Let L be a regular language. Then there exists an integer p ≥ 1 depending only on L such that every string w in L of length at least p (p is called the "pumping length"[4]) can be written as w = xyz (i.e., w can be divided into three substrings), satisfying the following conditions:

|y| ≥ 1;
|xy| ≤ p
for all i ≥ 0, xyiz ∈ L

Suppose I want to test regular expression 011
Since it is regular expressionm, there is string w for at least length p that satisfy w=xyz

The number of this automata is 3, p should be >= 3
But only string that accept this automata is 011
So I pick 011 as w
I can break up 3 part 011 = xyz 
but how can I break? I cannot satisfy 
|y| ≥ 1;
|xy| ≤ p
for all i ≥ 0, xyiz ∈ L

Since it is only accept 011
How can I pump? Where am I wrong

Comment: Pumping Lemma is for Regular Languages not expressions. What is the language in this question ?

Comment: @sinanspd: Every regular expression (in the CS sense) defines a unique regular language. In this case *L* = { "011" }.

Comment: @ruakh yeah I thought the language would be broader since pumping a language of a single expression is relatively easier

Answer (score 2):

Let *p* be 4. Then there are no strings *w* in *L* of length at least *p*, so any statement of the form "Every string *w* in *L* of length at least *p* […]" will be [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). So the pumping lemma is satisfied.

Answer (score -2):

Pumping lemma is generally applicable to infinite regular languages.
And is not used to prove L is regular
It is used to prove L is not regular
But it satisfies for all infinite regular languages